# Sub algebras of dimension $2$ of division algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, division-algebras

Let $U$ be a division algebra over the field $k$, and let $V$ be a sub algebra of dimension $2$. I read (in a recent answer on MathOverflow) that $V$ then necessarily is commutative, that is, $V$ is a field.

Can anyone explain why that is (or from what general theorem this follows) ?

Comment: You can always construct a basis for $V$ by taking one element to be the identity. Then the other element is some $v \in V$, and every element is a linear combination of $1$ and $v$, which commute.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: could you give some more details ? I assume that $[U : V] = 2$; you seem to use that $V$ is $2$-dimensional over $k$ ?

Comment: You said that $V$ is a subalgebra of dimension $2$; that means $2$-dimensional over $k$. The condition that $V$ is of *index* $2$ is quite different and does not guarantee commutativity as far as I know (but also seems to me to be pretty rare).

Comment: Please link to the question in MathOverflow. It is probably easy to check the intended meaning. For what it's worth, I would interpret the phrase *a subalgebra of dimension 2* the same way Qiaochu Yuan did. In his argument two can be replaced by any prime number, and the conclusion would be the same.